# Why the anonymous type instance cannot accept null values returned by the entity framework query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, anonymous-types

When I try to run the following Entity Framework query:

```
var l =  (from s in db.Samples
          let action = db.Actions.Where(x => s.SampleID == x.SampleID && x.ActionTypeID == 1).FirstOrDefault()
          where s.SampleID == sampleID
          select new 
          {
             SampleID = s.SampleID,
             SampleDate = action.ActionDate,
          }).ToList();
```

I get following exception:

> The cast to value type 'DateTime' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either **the result type's generic parameter** or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

The problem probably is that `Action.ActionDate` is defined as non nullable `DateTime` in EF model, but the query returns `null`  when there are no relevant actions assigned to `Sample`.

The workaround is to return a non-anonymous type with nullable properties, but why the anonymous type cannot accept the null result? Can the anonymous type be somehow forced to be created with nullable properties?

Comment: There are no generic types. There are anonymous types here. Anonymous types are "defined" at compile time

Comment: you can try `SampleDate = (DateTime?)action.ActionDate`

Comment: `Action.ActionDate is defined as non nullable DateTime in EF model` **that** is your problem.  It shouldn't be non-nullable in the model if the database column is nullable.

Comment: @Servy When the Sample's Action exists, it is allways created with ActionDate, but the Sample can exist with no actions of some ActionType, e.g. 1.  So in Action table/class it is non-nullable but can be NULL in a view.

Comment: @Servy The classical case is a `left join`... `ActionDate` could be non-nullable, but the result value could be `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using anonymous types, not generic types. Anonymous types are defined by the compiler at compile time. In the end it's like you created a

```
class MyEntity
{
    public readonly int SampleID;
    public readonly DateTime SampleDate;
}
```

The types are "selected" by the compiler based on the types you use at the right of the `=` in the `new`. So if SampleID is `int` and `ActionDate` is `DateTime` then those types will be used.

Now, what happens is that when the Entity Framework executes the query and "deserializes" the data in the "`MyEntity`" class, it tries to convert the `null` it received by the SQL to a `DateTime`, and the cast fails. The solution is to define the `ActionDate` as a `DateTime?` in the anonymous type:

```
SampleDate = (DateTime?)action.ActionDate,
```

or to give `SampleDate` a value when `ActionDate` is `null`:

```
SampleDate = (DateTime?)action.ActionDate ?? default(DateTime),
```

(this second solution is untested because I don't have an SQL Server near me, if it works `SampleDate` will be a `DateTime` and will contain the date returned by the query or `DateTime.MinValue` when the date is `null`)

Comment: Yes, piece of cake...  sometimes it is easier to ask than to think.Thanks